# Custom Event Listener in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, events, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have to integrate the Kafka and spring boot application in a little different way. My spring boot app can have N number of methods annotated with @EventListner(name ="xyz"). where xyz is a custom event name which is managed in the config file at a central repository. App has to identify which Kafka topic this event is coming via the config file. Events are posted by diff app.

```
 @Component("abc")
   public class Abc{

   @EventListner(name="xyz")
   public void mod(JSON x){
     //do something
   }
```

How can we achieve this, I have worked on kafkaListner it looks little diff.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `@EventListener` you can use `ApplicationListener` interface

for e.g.

```
@Component
public class SomeEventHandler 
  implements ApplicationListener<SomeEvent>{

  public void onApplicationEvent(SomeEvent e) {
     ///...
  }

}
```